# check if a Json file is modified or new item is added programmatically

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON file on my server with some data:

This is some part of my JSON:

```
{
"ringtones": [
    {
        "title": "Morning Alarm - Fur Elise",
        "link": "http://symphonyrecords.ir/rings/ala8_morning_alarm.mp3",
        "duration": "00:23",
        "id": 71,
        "genre": ["piano", "alarm"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Moein - Tolou",
        "link": "http://symphonyrecords.ir/rings/pia1_moein_tolou.mp3",
        "duration": "00:43",
        "id": 70,
        "genre": ["piano"]
    }

  ]
}
```

I show this information in a list view, So first I download and save this JSON file in a temp folder, and then I populate my list with the downloaded file.

This is how I get my JSON data

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ringtones");
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
    product.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("link"));
    product.setDuration(obj.getString("duration"));
    product.setId(obj.getInt("id"));

    JSONArray genreArray = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
    ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < genreArray.length(); j++) {
        genre.add((String) genreArray.get(j));
     }
product.setGenre(genre);
songList.add(product);
```

---

I don't want to push notification remotely|manually every time I add a new item in my JSON, So I need to programmatically check whenever a new item is added and show notification ***locally***.

I've prepared my notification method. but I have no idea how to do the check.

Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Using a checksum maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since every ringtone objects in the JSON contains an ID, you can keep a cache of the existing IDs and do check against that whenever you want or show notification locally whenever that cache is changed.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, please?